# Identify whether WebSphere Portal is installed

Tags: websphere-portal

How to identify if WebSphere portal is installed on the system. There is no records in the registry or in the "Installed Programs".

I know installation information is in IBM Installation manager files.

Maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

IBM has provided enough helps regarding that.

[IBM BOULDER](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wpf/inst_vfy.html)

Comment: Not very useful, as it does not say how to determine location. To run verification tools you need to know path, so if you know the path you know that WS portal is installed.

Answer (score 0):

location depends on your OS,
for linux/unix its **/opt/IBM/WebSphere**
for windows its in program files *or program files(x86)* IBM/WebSphere

just run the tools from there see the result